# How to input character in textfield

Tags: javafx, input, character, textfield

```
@FXML
public void handleAddButtonOnClick(ActionEvent actionEvent){

    String input = AddTextField.getText();
    try{
        System.out.println(hangman.check(input));
    }catch (Exception IO){
        System.out.println("ERROR: input is not character");
    }

}
```

The above code snippet yields the following compile time error:

```
check(char) in Hangman cannot be applied to(java.lang.String)
```

How can I fix it so I can input character in it?

This is my `check` method

```
public boolean check(char character) throws Exception {
    String temp = "";
    boolean isContain = false;
    if (this.keeper.contains("" + character)) {
        throw new Exception("Duplicate character");
    }


    this.keeper += character;
    for (int i=0 ; i< this.word.length();i++) {
        if (this.word.charAt(i) == character) {
            temp += character;
            isContain = true;
        } else {
            temp += this.result.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    if (!isContain) this.life--;
    this.result = temp;
    return  isContain;
}
```

Comment: The `TextField.text` property is of type `String`, since usually a `TextField` can contain any non-negative number of characters. Of course you can get the characters of a `String`, but you need to describe what should be done in case of string lengths != 1...

Comment: `if(input.length() > 0){(hangman.check(input.charAt(0));}`. I am guessing you are going to restrict your `TextField's` max length to only one character.

Comment: @Sedrick Thankyou now I can input it